# How can I hide a specific method in swagger-ui?

Tags: java, spring, swagger-ui

I am currently using version 2.9.2 of swagger-ui in Spring Boot 2. The methods I want to show for each operating environment are different, so I wonder how to do it. (env ex: test, dev, prod...)

For example, i want to show the A method in the dev environment, but i don't want to show it in the prod environment.

Using `@Profile("dev")`, the configuration of swagger-ui itself can be set differently for each environment, but what i want to do is show swagger, but i want to show specific methods differently for each environment..

Thank you in advance for the answers.

Added :

```
@EnableSwagger2
@Configuration
public class SwaggerConfig {

    @Bean
    public Docket testApi() {
        String apiDomain = "test";
        String apiName = apiDomain + " API";

        ApiInfo apiInfo = new ApiInfoBuilder()
                .title(apiName)
                .description(apiName + " Document Prototype")
                .version("0.0.1")
                .build();

        return new Docket(DocumentationType.SWAGGER_2)
                .groupName(apiDomain)
                .apiInfo(apiInfo)
                .select()
                .apis(getSelector(API_BASE_PACKAGE + "." + apiDomain))
                .paths(PathSelectors.any())
                .build();
    }

    private Predicate<RequestHandler> getSelector(String basePackage){

        // Profiles is a custom class util    
        return Profiles.isProd() ? Predicates.and(RequestHandlerSelectors.basePackage(basePackage), handler -> !handler.isAnnotatedWith(IgnoreForProd.class))
                : RequestHandlerSelectors.basePackage(basePackage);
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you used `@ApiIgnore` annotation to ignore the specific API?

Comment: Is the use case something like you want to show `/api/database-ui` for dev environment but not for production environment?

Comment: @HadiJ

You can disable A method from swagger using `@ApiIgnore`, but it seems a little different because what i want is to prevent certain methods from coming out in a specific environment. In other words, i want to show the effect of applying `@ApiIgonre` and `@Profile` together.

Comment: @ShababbKarim

Exactly, I don't want to show the methods of a specific controller in swagger-ui in a prod environment.

Comment: You can use eg custom annotation as an indicator and then apply endpoint filter based on that annotataion and env configuration.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For this you need to spring `@Profile` annotation to create custom `Docket` instances for the Swagger UI.

Lets say you want to ignore a specific controller method in the production environment.

First, you need to create a custom annotation. You can do so without it but this will have the cleanest solution.

```
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@Target(ElementType.METHOD)
public @interface IgnoreForProd {
}
```

Then annotate the method of controller that you want to ignore in production.

```
//..Spring and swagger annotations
@IgnoreForProd
public Pet postTestPetForSale(Pet pet) {
   //...controller code
}
```

Finally, you need to set up the docket instance for production.

```
@Profile("prod")
@Configuration
@EnableSwagger2
public class SwaggerConfig {

    @Bean
    public Docket postsApi() {
        return new Docket(DocumentationType.SWAGGER_2)
                .groupName("public-api")
                .apiInfo(apiInfo())
                .select()
                     // This is the part that will ignore the method
                    .apis((handler) -> !handler.isAnnotatedWith(IgnoreForProd.class))
                .build();
    }

    private ApiInfo apiInfo() {
        return new ApiInfoBuilder().title("API")
                .description("API reference for developers")
                .build();
    }

}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Your answer makes sense, but `not` doesn't work in my source. How can i use `not` method? (Sorry if it's a very basic question.)

Comment: `apis` method takes in a predicate. You can pass in a lambda that returns false for the class annotation. I have edited the answer. Please upvote the answer if you found it helpful. You can accept if it solves the question. Thanks.

Comment: If you follow the corrected answer, the method to which `@IgnoreForProd` is applied will not be visible, but Swagger-ui is created only in the prod environment because `@Profile("prod")` is present.

Is there any way to apply `!handler.isAnnotatedWith` only in prod environment as Swagger-ui is created in other environment? I thought about it based on the answers you gave, but I couldn't get a clear answer.

Comment: oh, I found the answer. Please refer to the edited text. Thank you for your answer.